# SQL Server 2014: Options to have stored procedure configuration settings in a table

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2014;

I am looking for options to have the stored procedure configuration settings in a SQL table, but cache them in memory (global variables) and avoid keep reading them from the configuration table.

Basically, I am looking for something like App.Config in SQL Server TSQL.

In ASP.NET or C#, applications we have the option of reading the configuration settings on 1st reference from the database and cache them in memory (like static class members of a ConfigManager class). I am looking for a similar approach for SQL Server TSQL.

I expect this should be a known pattern for TSQL and SQL Server, but I am not able to search because the search terms “SQL Server” and “Config” leads to SQL Server configuration manager, that it entirely different topic. A link to an online article would be a great help.

**Update 1**

I am adding more context to the question.

This is not about system level database options or settings.

When a database application needs to implement a heavy amount of business logic inside store procedures, some of the system behavior must be parameterized in a configuration management system.

This approach is very comparable with web.config’s  section in asp.NET applications. The database application I am working on does not interface with any .net application front-end. It includes a series of complex batch processes that run periodically.

A few example of such settings that must be configurable are:

- Min age of applicant
- Order total threshold

Each of the above settings configures the behavior of some stored procedures, so the config items can’t be a stored procedure local variable. It won't be a good design if I want to read a setting from a name value config table every time a dependent stored procedures called.

If I want to design and develop such  equivalent system in TSQL, I would create a function that reads the settings from a name-value config table at the 1st time, store them in a @@global variable or table then reference the @@global variable at later calls.

My question is if such  equivalent system in TSQL has already been implemented as I shouldn’t be the 1st developer working on such requirement.

Comment: what are the " store the stored procedure configuration setting"? reading values from a table is what a RBDMS is good at.....if that's your real bottleneck then SQL might not be the place for this logic.

Comment: @MitchWheat, there are settings the SP logic that you want to make them globally configurable. This should not be an unusual practice.

Comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/04/23/60185.aspx

Comment: @JorgeCampos, there are more into this concept than global variables. I can think of a few functions that read the config table values and store them in global variables on 1st use. But I am confused since I should not be the 1st one trying to do this. There should be a well established and tested set of scripts as a pattern to do this type of config management.

Comment: "there are settings the SP logic that you want to make them globally configurable" pass in as parameters. Global variables are not a good design.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dn511014%28v=sql.120%29.aspx? Note that unlike .NET SQL Server caches things by default, in other words "reading from table" does not mean that it will always read data from a hard drive. The first time data is read, it will read from hard drive into memory and then process data. It will not be deleted from memory unless something else needs that memory and the data has not been accessed for a long time.

Comment: I think you are confounding Application Layer with Databases Layer. You are completely mistaken when saying: `I expect this should be a known pattern for TSQL and SQL Server` This is the kind of configuration you create and maintain on your application layer. At the database level you can use tables to store configurations or even temporary tables (which would live for a connection session). Even though there were such configuration you would lost it as the application uses connection pooling and the configurations are alive per connection (or session, it is the same)...

Comment: Using persistent connection is a bad practice. For what you want works you would have to have a persistent connection from the startup of the system to the shutdown of it which would make it eventually slow.

Comment: @AllanXu so what are "the settings"? Default isolation level, some t-sql hints and db-options or your own custom business data, some constant strings?

Comment: I added more information to clarify the requirements I need to implement.

Comment: Why do you insist that "It won't be a good design if I want to read a setting from a name value config table every time a dependent stored procedures called. " is a bad design? Tables are global variables in SQL Server. I hope you are not warried about performance of reading a small table as it will likely be cached in memory after the first read? If you really want some abstruction then you can create a function to read this table and return the result to your SP.

Comment: @Alex, no I am not insisting. I just wanted to know how everyone else would implement it. If hitting the name/value config table on every config read is what most developers doing, then I have my answer.

Comment: @Allan Xu, how many parameters are you looking to store? One way I have seen this done it is to create a table with a column for every parameter name you need and have only 1 row of data. Advantages: your parameters are typed. Disadvantages: if you have a lot of them you may hit column count limitations, not to mention presentation issues if you try to select from this table.

Comment: @Alex, I expect I will have less than 50 configurable parameters.